# Override isEnabled in ArrayAdapter blocks UI thread

Tags: android, android-spinner

Block UI thread:

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.sp,
                        spinerShowList) {

                            @Override
                            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                                return !titles.get(position);    
                            }   

};
```

OK:

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.sp,
                    spinerShowList

);
```

I want to disable some positions in spinner, but if I override isEnabled at the second click in spinner item, UI thread get blocked and app no respond and I need to force app close.

Extra code:

```
            titles = new ArrayList<Boolean>();              
            titles.add(true);

            for (CsSubworkareas item : areas) {

                if (lastLocal.isEmpty()
                        || !lastLocal.equals(item.getStore())) {
                    lastLocal = item.getStore();
                    spinerShowList.add(lastLocal);
                    titles.add(true);

                } else {
                    titles.add(false);
                }

                spinerShowList.add("   " + item.getNam());
            }
```

Comment: Do you mind to paste more code, especially how the titles is initialised.

Comment: I don't think your logic in the second code block is sound. It looks like `titles` and `spinerShowList` are ending up with different sizes. Each time the `if` block executes, you're adding two elements to `spinerShowList`, but only one to `titles`. Check the `size()` of each after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problen im my logic in titles list. I fix it and ui thread don´t block more. But I don´t understand how a problem that should generate a null pointer exception blocks UI thread.